CSS soft transition on viewport resize
I have an image with a fixed position:


img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div style="height: 40px; background: white;">Menu</div>
<div style="height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
</div>
<div id="content" style="background: white">
 ...
</div>
```



On mobile browsers (Firefox iOS, Bromite Android, etc.), when scrolling down on the page, the address bar typically disappears which redefines the y = 0 coordinate. When that happens, the image jumps brutally, which is annoying.
Is there a way to make the jump smoother using an animation? From what I understand, CSS animations are to be applied only on CSS values that change, here the change comes from the viewport.

Please add some HTML to your post, ideally in a demo snippet.

I turned your code into a real code snippet. Can you see your problem with this snippet when you run it full screen?

The full-screen mode still run within an iframe or something.

I think your response implies that you cannot see the image jump? It could be due to the iframe, but you to try to modify the snippet to make it show your problem.

The problem is identified: y = 0 is being rewritten after the page is loaded, which triggers an image jump because the image sits at y=0 as per top: 0 in the CSS.

From what I understand the user-interface of the browser changes, with the address bar disappearing. Since in your browser the address bar is at the top, the page content moves up. This does however, as far as I can tell, not imply a rewriting of y-coordinates in CSS. This would also mean you cannot solve this in CSS. Then again, without being able to reproduce your problem, this remains guessing. Let's see what other people have to say....

You can make it with transitions.


img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 500ms;
}
<div style="height: 40px; background: white;">Menu</div>
<div style="height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
</div>
<div id="content" style="background: white">
 ...
</div>
```



If this didn't do the job then,
html, body{
    transition: 500ms;
}

